# Fullcalendar show events based on two select options

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar. My event source code is grabbing all calendar events.   The event source is JSON:

```
[{ "id": "1", "provider_id": "18", "name":"chris cavage", "location_id":"1"}, 
 { "id": "2", "provider_id": "17", "name":"mark smith", "location_id":"2"}, ...
```

I have two select menus above the calendar to show the events based on the provider and location.  It's a way of filtering all of the calendar events:

```
Providers: <select id="calendar_provider_id">
              <option value="all">All...</option>
              <option value="17">Dr. Carl</option>
              <option value="18">Dr. Paul</option>
           </select>

 Location: <select id="calendar_location_id">
              <option value="all">All...</option>
              <option value="1">A-town</option>
              <option value="12">P-ville</option>
           </select>
```

When the select options change, I want to re-render the shown events. 
I have it working now for just the location select menu like this:

```
$('#calendar_location_id').change(function() {

            //rerender events for calendar: update the ones shown.
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');

        }
 });
```

And here's what I do for $('#calendar).fullcalendar({

```
events: 'json_appointments.php',
eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
            return ['all', event.location_id].indexOf($('#calendar_location_id option:selected').val()) >= 0;
        }
```

It works great for just the one select menu, but I cannot seem to understand how to make something like this work for both select options including the 'all' options.

Here's a fiddle to show you what I have so far.  How do I get the second menu option to work in conjunction with the first one so the filter works accordingly?

http://jsfiddle.net/michels287/7h2tn245/

Comment: Could you demo this in a fiddle?

Comment: No problem. Thanks. I updated my question with the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xz2mqLhd/

Relevant code changes inside fullCalendar config:

```
eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {
      // Check location AND provider id selection
      return ['all', event.location_id].indexOf($('#calendar_location_id option:selected').val()) >= 0 && ['all', event.provider_id].indexOf($('#calendar_provider_id option:selected').val()) >= 0;
    }
```

And also

```
// Trigger event rerendering on provider_id change too
$('#calendar_location_id, #calendar_provider_id').change(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  This will help me.  I am struggling to understand the eventRender syntax.  Can you explain how it's working? Is the return ['all',...]  part: is that part of fullcalendar's script or is that just basic jQuery?

Comment: It's just basic javascript/jQuery. Since you wanted both selects to filter I just added another condition like the first you already had - If the location is All or the specified location AND the provider is All or the specified provider, then it will return true, resulting in the event being rendered

Comment: Thanks again for helping me.  I appreciate it.